# how to apply a function to specific rows in SparkR in R while keeping the earlier results intact

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, subset, sparkr

I want to apply `ifelse` function to all rows with "GOOD"

my df is as follows:

```
item <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")  
volume <- c("10","2","4","6","3","6")  
general_flag <- c("GOOD","DROP","GOOD","GOOD","DROP","GOOD")
```

I'm trying

```
df$general_flag <- SparkR::when(df$item %in% c("B") & df$general_flag %in% c("GOOD") , ifelse(df$volume <= 5, "DROP", "GOOD"))
```

or even

```
df$general_flag <- df[df$item %in% c("B") & df$general_flag %in% c("GOOD"),]$volume <= 5, "DROP", "GOOD"))
```

but its making everything else null in general flag while following the condition for subset only, the result is as follows

```
item <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")
volume <- c("10","2","4","6","3","6")  
general_flag <- c(null,null,"DROP","GOOD","DROP",null)
```

I want to get the output as :

```
item <- c("A","A","B","B","B","C")  
volume <- c("10","2","4","6","3","6")  
general_flag <- c("GOOD","DROP","DROP","GOOD","DROP","GOOD")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(general_flag = case_when(volume <=5  & item == 'B'~ "DROP" , 
          TRUE ~ general_flag))
```

-output

```
# item volume general_flag
#1    A     10         GOOD
#2    A      2         DROP
#3    B      4         DROP
#4    B      6         GOOD
#5    B      3         DROP
#6    C      6         GOOD
```

---

Or with `ifelse`

```
df %>%
       mutate(general_flag = ifelse(volume <= 5 & item == "B", "DROP",
    general_flag))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(item, volume, general_flag)
```